# Intalling pg-trajectory on windows

Tags: postgresql, mingw32, pg

I am trying to install pg-trajectory on windows through mingw command window and while entering this line

```
$ mingw32-make PG_CONFIG=E:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_config.exe
```

I am encountering this error:

```
Process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, E:PostgresSQL9.5binpg_config.exe –pgxs, …) failed

Mingw32-make: *** No targets. Stop.
```

Is there is an alternative or solution to this? Kindly inform me

Answer (score 0):

Download library from source: https://bitbucket.org/gsudmlab/pg-trajectory

Execute `pg_trajectory--0.0.1.sql` file.

To execute, you can copy it and paste to psql or use command `\q pg_trajectory--0.0.1.sql`

Make sure you installed pre-requisite (PostGIS).

Alternatively, install.sh script should work as well.